# Windows 11 fullscreen games minimize or get interrupted

Tags: windows-11

Windows 11 full-screen games minimize or get interrupted. It happens after 22H2 update but happened before as well right after Windows 11 upgrade. It never happened on Windows 10.
It is an Asus laptop.

The solution for me was to disable the following windows services group that seem to be related to Conexant audio:

- CxAudioSvc
- CxAudMsg Service
- CxUIUSvc
- CxUtilSvc

I don't know what these services do, as I cannot see any difference other than the games working smoothly now.

Does anyone know what the root cause could be and have a better solution, or could explain what happens?

I've seen this problem mentioned on many forums but nowhere is this solution mentioned. I'll leave this here, maybe at least it will work for someone else.

Comment: If you don't need Conexant, just uninstall it. Or ensure that you have the latest version for your computer model. For example for [Lenovo](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds501810-conexant-audio-driver-for-windows-10-64-bit-thinkpad-e480-e580).

Comment: "I've seen this problem mentioned on many forums, but nowhere is this solution mentioned." - Because the solutions as simple as uninstalling the third-party software.

Comment: "full-screen games minimize or get interrupted" - Can you be more specific?

Comment: Every few minutes full-screen game loose focus, is minimized or just stops for a while. Sometimes exits to menu like you liked Esc. Depending on game.

Comment: @harrymc "just uninstall it." - it seems to be part of my Windows installation.